# Music Store 2 Tutorial - VB Conversion

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to asp.net and have been working through the tutorial - up to lesson 10, however I cannot get the partial view to work.

Controller:-
     '
        ' GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary

```
    <ChildActionOnly()>
    Public Function CartSummary() As ActionResult
        Dim cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(Me.HttpContext)

        ViewData("CartCount") = cart.GetCount()

        Return PartialView("CartSummary")
    End Function
```

Views:-
CartSummary:-

```
@modeltype TEST.Cart

@Html.ActionLink("Cart (" & ViewData("CartCount") & ")", _
                      "Index", _
                      "ShoppingCart", _
                      New With {.id = "cart.GetCount"})
```

_Layout:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewData("Title")</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h1>   ASP.NET MVC MUSIC STORE</h1>
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li class="first"><a href="@Url.Content("~")" id="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Store/")">Store</a></li>
            <li>@Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")</li>
            <li><a href="@url.Content("~/StoreManager/")">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
           @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error returned is "Expression does not produce a value".
I can remove the  tag and then display the CartSummary.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `Html.RenderAction` helper here's the correct syntax:

```
@Code
    @Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")
End Code
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
@Code @Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart") End Code
```

or if you want to use the the `Html.Action` helper this is the syntax:

```
@Html.Action("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")
```

Contrast those two with their C# equivalents:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}
@Html.Action("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart")
```

As a VB.NET guy you might find the [following article](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic) useful.

Comment: They way you have RenderAction written will not work for VB. This produces an "Expression does not produce a value" error in the IDE.

The @Html.Action syntax is correct though....